# Looking for terms similar to "New Era" and "Next Generation"

Tags: phrase-requests

Looking for terms similar to "New Era" and "Next Generation" that represent  being at the forefront of its industry with a focus on progress and innovation

Comment: "Same old, same old" is what those terms say to me. New! Improved!! Junk.

Comment: @JohnLawler agreed. And other pretentious jargon such as “cutting edge” and “paradigm breaking” could be added to the junk bin.

Answer (score 1):

**state-of-the-art**

> very modern and using the most recent ideas and methods:
>
> - *a state-of-the-art computer*
> - *The control panel uses all the newest technology and is considered state-of-the-art.*

[Cambridge dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/state-of-the-art)

Answer (score 1):

**cutting edge**

> the most modern stage of development in a particular type of work or activity:
>
> - *a company at the cutting edge of mobile communications technology*

[Cambridge dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/cutting-edge)

**bleeding edge**

> relating to or describing systems, devices, or ideas that are so modern that they are still being developed:
>
> - *bleeding-edge technology*

[Cambridge dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/bleeding-edge)

A cutting edge technology is the best that is commercially available; a bleeding edge technology might still be in the prototype or beta-testing stage. The bleeding edge, of course, is inside the thing the cutting edge is cutting.